# custom LocationProvider for mapbox 10

Tags: android, mapbox

how can i create custom Location provider for android mapbox 10 in java?
in fact, i have calibrated sensors that i used to calculate the location
and i want to set these locations with my own LocationProvider for LocationComponentPlugin

@Override
public void getLastLocation(@NonNull LocationEngineCallback callback) throws SecurityException {

```
    lastLocation=new Location.Builder().latitude(0).longitude(0).build();
    result = LocationEngineResult.create((List<android.location.Location>) lastLocation);
    callback.onSuccess(result);
}
```